# AWS "Serverless" architecture for real time client-server messenging

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, serverless-architecture

If i understood the whole concept correctly, the "serverless" architecture assumes that instead of using own servers or containers, one should use bunch of aws services. Usually such architecture includes Amazon API Gateway, bunch of Lambda functions and DynamoDB (or alternative) for storing data and state, as Lambda can't keep state. And such services as EC2 is not participating in all this, well, because this is a virtual server and it diminish all the benefits of serverless architecture.

All this looks really cool, but i feel like i'm missing something important, because right now this seems to be not applicable for such cases as real time applications.

Say, i have 2 users online. One of them performs an action in an app, which triggers changes in database, which in turn, should trigger changes in the second user app.

The conventional way to send some data or command from server to client is websocket connection. But with serverless architecture there seem to be no way to establish and maintain websocket connection. So... where did i misunderstood the concept? Or, if i understood everything correctly, then how do i implement the interactions between 2 users as described above?

Answer (score 4):

> where did i misunderstood the concept?

Your observation is correct. It doesn't work out of the box using API Gateway and Lambda.

Applicable solution as described [here](https://serverless.com/blog/serverless-notifications-on-aws/) is to use AWS IoT - yes, another AWS Service.

Comment: IoT. Internet of things. I have strong stereotype that if a service named IoT, then it's suppose to be used under the specific circumstances. In other words, it looks like it's not designed for "regular" mobile/web apps.

Comment: I went through the serverless example and thanks MaiKay, it seems it suits well for the purpose. @stkvtflw I think, regardless of the name the technology, this solution is usable for your scenario. Sometimes even aws finds it difficult to group services e.g Cognito (Can be used for Web as well as for Mobile and we are heavily using it for Web) but still listed under mobile category.

Answer (score 1):

Serverless isn't just a matter of Lambda, API Gateway and DynamoDB, it's much bigger than that. One of the big advantages to Serverless is the operational burden that it takes off your plate. No more patching, no more capacity planning, no more config management. Those may seem trivial but doing those things well and across a significant fleet of instances is complex, expensive and time consuming. Another benefit is the economics. Public cloud leverages utility billing, meaning you pay for what you run whether or not you actually use it. With AWS most of the billing per service is by hour but with Lambda it's per 100ms. The cheapest EC2 instance running for a full month is about $10/m (double that for redundancy). $20 in Lambda pricing gets you millions of invocations so for most cases serverless is significantly cheaper.

Serverless isn't for everything though, it has it's limitations, for example it's not meant for running binaries. You can't run nginx in Lambda (for example), it's only meant to be a runtime environment for the programming languages that it supports. It's also specifically meant for event based workloads, which is perfect for microservice based architectures. Small independent discrete pieces of compute doing work that when done they send an event to another(s) to do something else and if needed return a response.

To address your concerns about realtime processing, depending on what your code is doing your Lambda function could complete in less than 100ms all the way up to 5 minutes. There are strategies to optimize it's duration time but in general it's for short lived work which is conducive of realtime scenarios.

In your example about the 2 users interacting with the web app and the db, that could very easily be built using serverless technologies with one or 2 functions and a DynamoDB table. The total roundtrip time could be as low as milliseconds if not seconds, it really all depends on your code and what it's doing. These would all be HTTP calls so no websockets needed. Think of a number of APIs calling each other and your Lambda code is the orchestrator.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at SNS (simple notification service).  In your example, if app user 2 is a a subscriber to an SNS topic, then when app user 1 makes a change that triggers an SNS message, it will be pushed to the subscriber (app user 2).  The message can be pushed over several supported protocols (Amazon, Apple, Google, MS, Baidu) in addition to SMTP or SMS.  The SNS message can be triggered by a lambda function or directly from a DynamoDB stream after an update (a database trigger).  It's up to the app developer to select a message protocol and format.  The app only has to receive messages through its native channels.  This may not exactly be millisecond-latency 'real-time', but it's fast enough for all but the most latency-sensitive applications.

I've been working on an AWS serverless application for several months now, and am amazed at the variety of services available. The rate of improvement and new features being added is enough to leave you out-of-breath.